# Running Elasticsearsch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

Good day.
Can anyone help me?
I try to run elastic, but in the command line write that elastic already running and nothing happens in the browser.

I try run http://localhost:9200/, but require a login and password.

What do I wrong?

Comment: What are the logs?

Comment: The default username is "elastic" and password is "changeme"

Comment: [2021-03-29T07:57:23,485][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [User] Exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid port range: 127.0.0.1
 at java.net.SocketPermission.init(SocketPermission.java:444) ~[?:?]
 at java.net.SocketPermission.<init>(SocketPermission.java:299) ~[?:?]
 at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addSocketPermissionForPortRange(Security.java:283) ~[elasticsearch-7.12.0.jar:7.12.0]